# How does file cache invalidation works in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, caching

I am caching a API response depending on app version making the incoming request.

Lets say `@banks` is cached with a `cache_key` `'all_products_#{@version}'` with timestamp say 20160926160000

for version v3 we have cached_file which is returned with `cache_key` `'all_products_v3'`

for version v5 we have cached_file which is returned with `cache_key` `'all_products_v5'`

my question is, after the file is cached, a bank record is updated. now when `cache_key` `'all_products_v3'` is called it should return the latest updates. How is this invalidation happening?

1. when request comes with `timestamp(20160926160000)`(old) how is new cache file identified and forwarded to db to get the updates?

As per my understanding request has old timestamp and updates are present in DB only. Is there any hook that is running when db is updated and new cache files created?.